# Относительный путь к файлам в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

если указать путь к файлу

```
E:\\IdeaProjects\\MyProject\\01\\src\\main\\java\\org\\Council\\test.txt
```

Идея файл видит, а
в таком варианте:

```
src/main/java/org/Council/test.txt
```

не работает

Причем на на другом ПК вариант с указанием относительного пути (последнего) работает (один проект).

пробовал делать Copy Relative Path - вставлял скопированный путь, бесполезно

где в настройках ИДЕИ можно задать?

File - Project Structure - Modules
пробовал, безрезультатно

пробовал класть файл рядом, в одном каталоге, тоже не работает.
по поиску проделанные советы не помогли

Comment: зависит от того, откуда открыл проект

Comment: не совсем понял ответ

Comment: покажи скрншот вкладки project

Comment: в проджект стракче все верно http://take.ms/IIFfz

Comment: нужно писать `./src/main/java/org/Council/test.txt`

Comment: действительно, вы правы! Спасибо! не могли  бы вы обьяснить почему настройки (Project Structure) и копирование путей через Copy Relative Path противоречат тому что вы указали, а тем более на одном пк в идее без "./" ошибку не выдает а мне надо добавлять два символа

Answer (score 4, accepted):

когда открываешь как проект, то пути начинаются с папки этого проекта. поэтому пути нужно указывать с `./src/main/`

В вашем случае будет `./src/main/java/org/Council/test.txt`

Напоминаю, что `./src/main/java/org/Council/` не предназначена для хранения ресурсов. для этого используйте папку `resources`