# FileInputStream не видит файл, хотя проверка на наличие файла проходит успешно

Tags: java, файлы

Перестал работать `FileInputStream`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pathToDBUpdateFile = "C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Постпроцессинг/Макет суточных данных 2016.xls";
    File updateSourceFile = new File(pathToDBUpdateFile);
    System.out.println("FileName: " + updateSourceFile.getPath());
    System.out.println("Available file: " + !(updateSourceFile == null));
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(updateSourceFile);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Файл " + pathToDBUpdateFile + " не найден");
    }
}
```

При этом в консоль выводится следующее:

> FileName: C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Постпроцессинг\Макет суточных данных 2016.xls
>
> Available file: true
>
> Файл C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Постпроцессинг/Макет суточных данных 2016.xls не найден

Т.е. сам файл найден, а `FileInputStream` его видеть не хочет.
К тому же перестал работать заведомо рабочий ранее код. В чем дело, где искать причину?

---

Стал жертвой собственной невнимательности. Файл был формата xlsx, а не xls. Но отсюда вопрос: почему `!(updateSourceFile == null)` выдал `true`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625194/Относительный-путь-к-файлам-в-intellij-idea

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496747/Каким-способом-лучше-указывать-путь-к-файлу-в-программе-на-языке-j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему `!(updateSourceFile == null)` выдал `true`?

Потому что `updateSourceFile` - это объект, который всегда создаётся (`new File(...)`) и, соответственно, никогда не равен `null`. Независимо от пути до файла

Для проверки существования файла есть метод [exists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()):

```
System.out.println("Available file: " + updateSourceFile.exists());
```

---

И не по вопросу: на мой взгляд, `(updateSourceFile != null)` смотрится куда лучше и понятнее, чем `!(updateSourceFile == null)`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить путь к файлу:

```
String  pathToDBUpdateFile =  "C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\Постпроцессинг\\Макет суточных данных 2016.xls";
```

Comment: Не сработало. Интересен тот факт, что файл то найден, 
System.out.println("Available file: " + !(updateSourceFile == null)); выдает True